# How can I subtract a vertex from another vertex?

Tags: c++, gdi

For my uni assignment I need subtract a vertex from another vertex

The task: Construct vector a by subtracting vertex 1 from vertex 0.

the professor gave us the body of the method and we need to fill it, in order to work for every vertex

The body of the method:

Vector MinusToVector(const Vertex &other) const;

The use of the Method:

Vector VectorA = vertex 1. MinusToVector(vertex0);

I am fighting with this task for more than an hour and I can't do it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question is coming from homeworks

Answer (score 0):

This usually works:

```cpp
Vector Vector::MinusToVector(const Vertex &other) const {
  return Vertex(this->X - other.x, this->y - other.y, this->z - other.z);
}
```

By the way your professor gave you the declaration, not the body of the method.

Make sure to include the declaration inside the Vector class/struct body.